# After deleting contents of the .gradle/caches directory , getting the error as Failed to create Jar file

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, gradle-cache

> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\Avani.gradle\caches\jars-9\992c2f3a0eb58806fe1b8305e8571da1\gradle-7.3.1.jar.

I got this error particularly after deleting the files in the .gradle/caches/ folder.

Comment: Looks like you have a Gradle process running. Try executing `./gradlew --stop` and try again

Answer (score 0):

try gradle clean
then invelidate caches and restart it works for me

Comment: Actually I tried the clean and invalidate caches but didn't work for me, so re-installed Android Studio and solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).